# Saving SGD Classifier with Dictvectorizer vocabulary

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to save a trained SGD classifier.I am using Divtvectorizer.But after loading the pickled classifier when i am using it for prediction i am getting following error

```
AttributeError: 'DictVectorizer' object has no attribute 'vocabulary_'
```

How can this be solved and can we save the vocabulary of dictvectorizer?

Thanks

Below is the code:

```
vecto= DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
transformer=vecto
X_train=transformer.fit_transform(features(sents))
X_test=transformer.transform(features(test))
y_test=[-1,1]
clf=SGDClassifier(alpha=0.2,loss='hinge',n_jobs=5)
clf=clf.partial_fit(X_train[:2],labels[:2],classes=[-1,1])
clf.partial_fit(X_train[2:3],labels[2:3],classes=[-1,1])
print clf.predict(X_test)
print clf.score(X_test,y_test)
```

Comment: Can we see the code please? The `vocabulary_` attribute is set during training. Are you saving the vectorizer before or after you've trained it?

Comment: can we save the vectorizer??If so can you please explain how??I am pickling the classifier.

Comment: A classifier and the vectorizer that produced the data the classifier was trained on must always be used together. You should pickle both. To save yourself some time, you can put both in a `Pipeline` and pickle that.

Comment: problem is that i am using partial_fit so can't use Pipeline..i know to pickle classifier by how to pickle vectorizer with the data??

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: @mbatchkarov i have posted the code...

Comment: You can pickle the pair `(vectorizer, clf)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pickle` library to save and load your `SGDClassifer` as well as your `DictVectorizer` likes this:

```
import pickle

# save SGDClassifier
with open('model.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(clf,f)

# load SGDClassifier
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    clf2 = pickle.load(f)
```

And analogous for your `DictVectorizer`:

```
# save DictVectorizer
with open('transformer.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(transformer,f)
 
# load DictVectorizer
with open('transformer.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    transformer2 = pickle.load(f)
```